# How to pass data between ViewModel in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-jetpack-compose

I am creating a food order app, and I have two screens: the home screen and the detail screen. The home screen displays a list of dishes, and when a dish is clicked, the app should navigate to the detail screen to display more information about that dish. However, I am unsure how to pass data from the home screen view model to the detail screen view model so that the app knows which dish to display.

Here is my home screen view model

```
class HomeViewModel : ViewModel() {
private val database = Firebase.database
private val myRef = database.getReference("foods")
private val _homeState = MutableStateFlow(HomeState())
val homeState: StateFlow<HomeState> = _homeState.asStateFlow()

init {
    myRef.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: ")
            // This method is called once with the initial value and again
            // whenever data at this location is updated.
            val value = dataSnapshot.getValue<Map<String, FoodData>>()
            value?.let {
                _homeState.value = _homeState.value.copy(
                    foodList = it.values.toMutableList()
                )
            }
            if (value != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Value is: ${_homeState.value.foodList}")
            }
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            // Failed to read value
            Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException())
        }
    })
}

companion object {
    const val TAG = "HomeViewModel"
}}
```

I look forward to any advice or suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Have a look at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#nav-with-args

when you have multiple screens, you should use a NavHost to navigate, and with that you can pass arguments when you call navhost.navigate()

Comment: Or consider... a shared view model?

Comment: So, which solution should I choose? Also, I'm wondering if having two view models on one screen is a bad practice because I believe that each screen should have only one view model.

Comment: Two view models for a screen is fine if they represent different things so they don’t have to directly communicate.